# How can I bring back the load indicator in the (sherlock) listview when refreshing?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Observe the image below. This is displayed in place of the ListView data before I set the `ListAdapter` in my `SherlockListFragment`. I don't know if this is a product of SherlockActionBar or standard Android, but in any case - how do I bring it back at a later point? My use case is that I have a refresh button and when the user presses that I want the list to clear and the spinner to appear again while loading.

[image: Image of load indicator (spinner)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `SherlockListFragment`, call `setListShown(false);`

The documentation for the compatibility [`ListFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html#setListShown%28boolean%29) (which `SherlockListFragment` extends from) states:

> Control whether the list is being displayed. You can make it not
>   displayed if you are waiting for the initial data to show in it.
>   During this time an indeterminant progress indicator will be shown
>   instead.

Then of course, once you finish refreshing, call `setListShown(true);`

Answer (score 1):

Recomendation call

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected
    // list item
    // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is
    // available.)
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment) != null) {

        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        setListShown(true);
    }
}
```